# Next stuck loading when using SASS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sass

Fresh Next project:

```
npm i --save-dev sass
```

Then in `/pages/_app.tsx` I write at the top:

```
import '@/assets/globals.scss;
```

The file exists and the path is correct. But the project doesn't load. If I run `npm run dev`, the website is stuck loading forever and the console just says:

> ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000

If I run `npm run build`, it's stuck with

> Creating an optimized production build...

The console doesn't display any error or warning, nothing. I've tried running these commands with `--verbose`, but nothing useful. If I change the file to `.css` and import `...css`, then everything works fine. I change it back to `.scss`, and stuck again.

I didn't add any next configuration.

- Next.js version: 13.1.2
- Sass version: ^1.57.1
- Node version: v14.20.0 (I can't upgrade because all of my projects crash)
- OS: Mac OSX

I've tried to search for this error 'cause I thought someone else would have it, but I find nothing. I've also checked the official Next Github issues page. I've tried to find errors or warnings in the console, but nothing. I've followed the official Next documentation, and as I say is a fresh project, nothing special. And as I said, If I remove `.scss` files and use only `.css`, the project works.

Sorry for not being able to provide more info. If you need something else please ask and I will edit the question.

EDIT:
don't know if it's related, but while I fixed this problem I tried to compile myself `.scss` files into `.css`, and use `.css` because then my project works.

I tried to run

```
node-sass ./styles.scss
```

and it displayed this error:

> Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X
> Unsupported architecture (arm64) with Node.js 14.x

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the error in your edit, it seems to be an incompatibility between latest `Next.js` and `Node 14`. There is an issue in the Next repo [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/45052#issuecomment-1408955264) that looks very similar, with 2 possible fixes:

- Revert Next.js to 13.1.1
- Or upgrade Node to 16 or 18

---

**EDIT 2023-09-07**

It should be fixed in NextJS [v13.4.5](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v13.4.5).